# Nested resources no route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-resources

I am trying to get a basic nested resource path to work but am currently getting the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stores"}
```

In my view I have the following links:

```
 <% if current_user %> Hello <%= current_user.email %> /
  <%= link_to 'Store', user_store_path %> 
    <%= link_to 'New Store', new_user_store_path %>
    <%= link_to 'My Profile', home_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', update_path %>
    <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %> 
   <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Login", login_path %> / <%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %>
  <% end %>
```

Now when I rake my routes the paths I am being given match exactly those above - user_store_path etc..

My routes file looks like this:

```
   resources :users do
     resources :stores
   end

   match "signup" => "users#new"
   match "home" => "users#show"
   match "update" => "users#edit"

   get "login" => "sessions#new"
   post "login" => "sessions#create"
   delete "logout" => "sessions#destroy"
   get "logout" => "sessions#destroy"

   resources :sessions

   root :to => 'sessions#new'
```

This really is confusing me a lot because everything I have read on the RoR website suggests that this should work. Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Do you have `StoresController` that has a `show` action?

Comment: Can you try `<%= link_to 'Store', user_store_path(1,1) %>`?

Comment: do bundle exec rake routes in your console and see what route points to new store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :users do
  resources :stores
end
```

creates `store` routes which all require a given `user` since it is nested.

So e.g. `<%= link_to 'Store', user_store_path %>` is wrong because it doesn't provide any user. It should be `<%= link_to 'Store', user_store_path(current_user, store) %>`.

This also applies to your other links, e.g. `<%= link_to 'New Store', new_user_store_path %>` which should be `<%= link_to 'New Store', new_user_store_path(current_user) %>`

**update based on your comment**

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stores" [...]` occurs because you want to `show` a particular resource, in this example a `store`. Therefore, you need to pass in the store id or the store object to generate the path/url. E.g. `<%= link_to 'Store', user_store_path(current_user, current_user.store.first %>`. I missed that on my initial answer, sorry.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! unfortunately the same error is still occuring but it's also trying to pass all of the current_user's details `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stores", :user_id=>#<User id: 2, email: "t_pinchen@yahoo.co.uk", password_digest: "$2a$10$LRtN245KG3m74EM/4TdvTOtgKVKwItlV68u4wDmwScvx..."` Do you know how I can fix this? :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to specify the path, you must also specify the objects or their id.
For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Store', [current_user, store] %>
<%= link_to 'Store', user_store_path(user_id: current_user.id, id: store.id) %>
<%= link_to 'New Store', new_user_store_path(user_id: current_user.id) %>
#and so on
```

Run rake routes and you will see that in some paths you want to specify id, for example: `/users/:user_id/stores/:id`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects